# programmatic access to google-sheets-api 'Insert Note' notes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Given a Google Sheets document, is there any way to programmatically access the notes produced from 'Insert Note' in the Google Sheets web interface?

I searched in the Python v4 API documentation, but couldn't find a reference to 'note' anywhere:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/

If there is a way to do it via google apps script, I would like to know how such script could be run from the command-line in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get):

Your [notes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData) will be at

```
sheets[].data[].rowData[].values[].note
```

in the Response body.

FieldMask:

```
sheets(data(rowData(values(note))))
```

[API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?spreadsheetId=yourssIdHere&ranges=A1%253AB2&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(note)))))